# Change titles for each subplot using loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot, title

I am trying to change title of each subplot using loop in R. I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294879/different-titles-for-plots-using-loop-in-r) but I was not able to apply this in my case. Here are my data and codes:

```
# Pet size data and their names
color <- c('W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G')
mass <- c(10, 14, 20, 11, 16, 13, 11, 15, 10, 14, 23, 18, 12, 22, 20, 13, 14, 17)
name <- c('B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E')

# Make it into data frame
pet.stats <- data.frame(color, mass, name)

# Name of pets (I want to plot them by type of pets)
kitty <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
bunny <- c('D', 'E', 'F')

all.pets <- append(kitty, bunny)
all.pets <- as.factor(all.pets)

par(mfrow = c(2, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))

# Loop through pet names and give title with pet type and pet name for each subplot
for (i in 1: nlevels(pet.stats$name)) {
barplot(pet.stats$mass[pet.stats$name == levels(pet.stats$name)[i]],
main = substitute(paste('Size of ', bold('lovely'),
ifelse(pet.stats$name[i] %in% kitty, 'kitty', 'bunny'),
' (', levels(pet.stats$name[i]), ')')),
xlab = 'Color', ylab = 'Mass', names = c('White', 'Black', 'Gray'))
abline(h = 0)
}
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

I want each subplot to have a title "Size of **lovely** (pet type) (pet name)" such as "Size of **lovely** bunny 'D'"

Could somebody please help fix what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It seems like `substitute()` doesnt get variables. As a sidenote, shouldn't `pet name` be obtained using something like `as.character(pet.stats$name[i]))`? Else you give a vector with all the levels.

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659096/italics-in-title-of-lattice-graph

Comment: Thanks for the URL. I did not see this one before I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here is you solution. The problem was with R and non-standard evaluation. The `substitute` function was freezing the evaluation of functions. The way to get the desired behaviour, is to specify in the `env` variable what you need to have evaluated.

Note, I broke out each of the variables and then constructed them in the `main`. This makes it a little easier to see what is happening.

```
# Pet size data and their names
color <- c('W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 
           'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G', 
           'W', 'B', 'G', 'W', 'B', 'G')
mass <- c(10, 14, 20, 11, 16, 13, 11, 15, 
          10, 14, 23, 18, 12, 22, 20, 13, 14, 17)
name <- c('B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 
          'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 
          'C', 'E', 'E', 'E')

# Make it into data frame
pet.stats <- data.frame(color, mass, name)

# Name of pets (I want to plot them by type of pets)
kitty <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
bunny <- c('D', 'E', 'F')

all.pets <- append(kitty, bunny)
all.pets <- as.factor(all.pets)
```

Now note the list of variables passed to `substitute`

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))

# Loop through pet names and give title with pet type and pet name for each subplot
for (i in 1: nlevels(pet.stats$name)) {

# Break out the names
  animal_type <- ifelse(pet.stats$name[i] %in% kitty, 'kitty', 'bunny')
  animal_names <- levels(pet.stats$name)[i]

  barplot(pet.stats$mass[pet.stats$name == levels(pet.stats$name)[i]],
          main = substitute(paste('Size of ', bold('lovely'),
                                  animal_type,
                                  ' (', animal_names, ')'),
                            env = list(animal_type = animal_type,
                                       animal_names = animal_names)),
          xlab = 'Color', ylab = 'Mass', names = c('White', 'Black', 'Gray'))
  abline(h = 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked and gave me exactly what I wanted! I will check env variable I was not aware of here (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/substitute).